# Android humidity sensor manifest

Tags: android

I want to use the uses-feature in android to limit my app to only be visible on the play store to devices with a humidity sensor, but I cant find on developer.android.com what the delimited would be for that sensor.

I know that for accelerometer is like this:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
    android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no way to do that using `<uses-feature>`**

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) about `<uses-feature>`.

I know alternative solution : when user turn on application, you're getting a list of sensors and if there is not hydrometr, you're showing toast :

> "You cannot use that application, because your device hasn't got
>   required sensor"

Comment: Right, but I need to limit my app to only be installed on devices with a Hyrometer, your solution would allow users to install the app.

Comment: @Chrystian I changed my answer

Comment: That feature is key to my app, so installing the app on a device without that would be useless. I will have to manually exclude all devices but the GS4. Thank you.